# Displaying intersecting roads and creating multiple labels for long roads in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology

I am new to GIS and I am using QGIS 1.7.3 on Windows.

Can any one tell me how to display a map from line shapefile with these two characteristics:

1. Roads are displayed with borders at the sides and intersect at crossroads
2. Name label for long roads are duplicated at specified intervals

Here is the link to an image that illustrates my idea:

[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/MlvnVJmY1MMXqI5AR-B66fiYNl9YxKwsJ_DSpLaCxjs?feat=directlink]

(The map was taken from *underdark*'s blog)

This is the best I can achieve by drawing lines with two overlapping simple line, one slightly bigger than the other:

[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/80tHFuFnw0SrXG2Us8jLgPiYNl9YxKwsJ_DSpLaCxjs?feat=directlink]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make "real" crossroads and avoid overlapping lines symbols you need to activate symbol levels[image]

As for the repeated labels, try splitting the road in chunks (by the way, other gis software has an option to draw a label every "x" units?)

Comment: Giovanni, thanks a lot for your "symbol levels" tip. My map look much nicer now with "real" crossroads.
I don't know if other gis software has option to draw label every "x" units. Qgis is my first gis software ever and I am just a newbie. That's just my idea of how things should be done. Do you suggest any tool to split the roads into chunks?

Comment: to split manually you have the "split" tool in the editing toolbar.

Comment: I've found a way to split line layers automatically: import line layer into GRASS (using GRASS plugin), start v.split, enter input, output vector map, enter  either maximum segment length or maximum number of vertices in segment, hit "Run" and "View ouput" to see the product.

Comment: Just to update QGIS has now for a while option to repeat labels on single feature.