# Remove transition between two lines

Tags: qgis, line

I'm trying to display a highway on a map. But there is a transition between the lines (see picture within the red circles) that I would like to remove. Does anyone know how to remove the transition that the lines are showed continuously?

[image: Lines with transition]

Comment: Those are the nodes/vertices creating your lines. If you remove those, your line will cease to exist (in its current form).

Comment: Yes I know that, but I'm wondering if there's a tool/function that 'removes' those visible nodes so that it looks like it's one line

Comment: Is this what you need? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/423272/52808 See the answers regarding Geometry Generator or SAGA smoothing tool.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just want the yellow line to be continuous without the orange breaks in between:)

Comment: what about https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/163665/79

Comment: or https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/20214/79

Answer (score 1):

The number of vertices should make the line appear smooth enough for the scale at which it is used (more zoomed out than in your image). It depends on the resolution of your data.

If you want to 'fake' a smoother line, try using the `Vector Geometry -> Smooth` processing algorithm. Ironically, this will add *more* vertices to give the appearance of a smoother curve.

Original lines:
[image]

After running Smooth with 4 iterations and 1m offset:
[image]